# Combinatorial puzzler

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I'm wondering what the best way of solving the following problem is:

I have at the moment a `Map<String, Collection<String>>`. Let's say its a map of meals with a collection of beverages you could serve at that meal. E.g.

Breakfast - Orange Juice
Breakfast - Coffee

Lunch - Orange Juice
Lunch - Soda
Lunch - Beer

Dinner - Soda
Dinner - Beer
Dinner - Wine

So my collection really is `Map<Meal, Collection<Beverage>>`

What I need to do is create a `List<Map<String,String>>` of all the various combinations of beverages over the meals. I will have in this case 18 combinations. E.g.

[

[
Breakfast -> Orange Juice,
Lunch -> Orange Juice,
Dinner -> Soda
]

[
Breakfast -> Orange Juice,
Lunch -> Orange Juice,
Dinner -> Beer
]

[
Breakfast -> Orange Juice,
Lunch -> Orange Juice,
Dinner -> Wine
]

[
Breakfast -> Orange Juice,
Lunch -> Soda,
Dinner -> Soda,
]

etc...
]

I'm interested in seeing how others would go about creating the final collection.

Also, I'm using java, so nifty functional stuff is off limits.

Thanks

## EDIT

Meal types are dynamic. That is, dinner could be removed from the list or brunch added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, there's no magic here, just iterate over 3 collections in a nested loop.

```
for (String breakfastBev : breakfast) {
  for (String lunchBev : lunch) {
    for (String dinnerBev : dinner) {
      System.out.println(breakfastBev + ", " + lunchBev + ", " + dinnerBev);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure now you can figure out how to do it with your `Map` and output `List`. :-)

**EDIT**: For the changed requirements, one way to do it is recursion:

```
main() {
    List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    recordBeverages(new HashMap(), beveragesByMeal, output);
}

void recordBeverages(Map visited, Map meals, List<Map> output) {
    if(meals.isEmpty()) {
        output.add(visited);
    }
    String mealType = meals.keySet().iterator().next();
    Map remainingMeals = new HashMap(visited);
    remainingMeals.keySet().remove(mealType);
    for(Beverage bev : meals.get(mealType)) {
        Map newVisited = new HashMap(visited);
        newVisited.put(mealType, bev);    

        recordBeverages(newVisited, remainingMeals, output);
    }
}
```

Not tested, but you get ths idea.

Comment: Ah, I should add that I don't know how many meal types there are. E.g. Brunch could be added. Nevertheless, I think you may be correct in that I'm over thinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of counters with as many counters as there are meals. In a loop increase the first one until it reaches the last beverage for the first meal and then increase the next on (trickling down). When the last beverage of the last meal is reached you are done.

I'll leave the code for that up to you.

Comment: This is how I have implemented it, so it's good to have reassurance that it was an acceptable way. Thanks.